# Version Control / Code repository for SqlServer stored procedures and views

Tags: sql-server, database, version-control

Any recommendations for a database equivalent of SVN or GIT for use to check stored procedures and views out and in, and provide version control?

I am interested in open source / free solutions, but if you have a commercial solution, preferably low cost, please let me know also.

I have looked at answers here that talk about adding a entire database backup to a code repository, or comparing records, but that is not what I am talking about here.

I would like to check out a stored procedure, and check it back in knowing that no one else has touched it in the meanwhile.

I would like to see what changes have been made to the stored procedures and views since the last time I worked on the data access layer (even if there is no impact on my code).

Answer (score 1):

Our company uses Visual Studio Database Edition to manage our database schema (schema, not data). At this point, we would be lost without it. Our entire database schema is managed by Microsoft TFS, and is our "source of truth" with regards to what our schema looks like. It does much more than source control as well, including database validation, test data generation, refactoring etc.

Great tool.

Comment: TFS is way overkill for the size of our organization.

Comment: @Lill - Then perhaps Red-Gate's tool would be a better fit (http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Source_Control/index.htm)

Comment: Looks like it might be ok, but I should have asked for open source / free solutions. I will modify my question.

Comment: Just a note to say that as well as TFS and SVN, SQL Source Control now has Vault and SVN support. More details here: http://www.red-gate.com/MessageBoard/viewtopic.php?t=12265 (We're hoping to add static data support in the next EA)

Answer (score 1):

We use liquibase which you can find here:
http://www.liquibase.org/

It is open and extensible.  Published under the Apache 2.0 license.

and here is a tutorial on managing database schema changes with liquibase:
http://bytefilia.com/managing-database-schema-changes-liquibase-existing-schema/

You should have the repository in source control be the only source of the truth, with a periodic refresh of the database procedures (Continuous Integration) from the source control system.  The user with write/create permissions for the stored procedures should be the one CI service runs under.  This is the only way you can ensure no one is adding\changing objects in db rather than in the source of the truth (source control)

You can set up liquibase with SVN or GIT, and also any JDBC db, so SQL Server or most others as well.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not entirely what you had in mind - but it's worth reading this article: 
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/Database_CI.aspx
or googling "continuous database integration".

Broadly speaking, as a schema can be defined in text, any source code repository can be used to store it. What you probably really need is to know which version you're currently looking at, whether it's older or newer than the one in production, and what changes have happened when. The TFS solution gives you a lot of that, but you can also roll your own - though you'll probably need to script the way database changes are managed in your various environments.